# wget errors breaks shell script - how to prevent that?

Tags: shell, error-handling, wget

I have a huge file with lots of links to files of various types to download. Each line is one download command like:

wget 'URL1'

wget 'URL2'

...

and there are thousands of those.

Unfortunately some URLs look really ugly, like for example:
http://www.cepa.org.gh/archives/research-working-papers/WTO4%20(1)-charles.doc
It opens OK in a browser, but confuses wget.

I'm getting an error:

./tasks001.sh: line 35: syntax error near unexpected token `1'

./tasks001.sh: line 35: `wget 'http://www.cepa.org.gh/archives/research-working-papers/WTO4%20(1)-charles.doc''

I've tried both URL and 'URL' ways of specifying what to download.

Is there a way to make a script like that running unattended?
I'm OK if it'll just skip the file it couldn't download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to used double-quotes (") and not single quotes (') around the URL.

If that still doesn't work, try escaping the paren characters `(` and `)` with a backslash: `\(` and `\)`

Which shell are you using? Bash? zsh?

Answer (score 6):

Do not (ab)use the shell.

Save your URLs to some file (let's say my_urls.lst) and do:

```
wget -i my_urls.lst
```

Wget will handle quoting etc on it's own

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question but:

Both of the following commands work directly in a bash shell:

```
wget "http://www.cepa.org.gh/archives/research-working-papers/WTO4%20(1)-charles.doc"
```

and

```
wget 'http://www.cepa.org.gh/archives/research-working-papers/WTO4%20(1)-charles.doc'
```

Can you check to see if either of those work for you?

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that your shell is doing something with the ( characters.  I would try using double quotes " instead of single quotes ' around your URL.

If you wish to suppress errors you can use a >/dev/null under unix to redirect standard output or 2> /dev/null to redirect standard error.  Under other operating systems it may be something else.